# iTunes Promo codes and app updates

Tags: iphone

If a user has installed my app by redeeming a promo code and we're inside the 4 week window and I push an update to the app, will they receive the update to the app and be able to update it?

I guess more directly: If I can have 50 promo code installs per update and I do 2 releases in the 4 week time period do I wind up with 100 total promo code users (50 for each release) that are active for 2 weeks of overlap, or do the first 50 users apps stop working when the new update is 'ready for sale'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promo codes are valid for four weeks. An app purchased using one is the same as a normally purchased app. So, yes, they would get your updates within and after that four week period.

Comment: If you successfully passed out all 100, and it was within the 4 week availability window, your customer would get whatever version was available on the App Store at that moment

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iTunesConnect response.  I requested some Promo Codes and the download option never appeared, I asked iTunesConnect to send them to me again, but the response took so long I was ready for an upgrade.  Their reply suggests that once I upgrade my app, the previous promo codes will no longer work.  I don't want to send out promo codes that don't work, that would be a bad start for a reviewer.

iTunesConnect Response
"I see that recently you began to prepare to upload a new version of your binary, with version 1.1 now in the Waiting for Upload status. With every version of your app you receive 50 promo codes. Therefor with this new app version, your promo codes reset. In your email you requested that we return the promo codes to you that you requested and never received, however these promo codes were for the old version and once the new one goes live will cease to work."